# Prevent focus switch to main form on fly out IsOpen=false;

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a MetroWindow. It has a Flyout. The Flyout has a button. When the Flyout button is pressed, a new MetroWindow is shown and the flyout is dismissed.

What occurs is:

1. User pressed button on Flyout.
2. The button-press opens a new non-modal form and sets the Flyout's IsOpen to false.
3. The non-modal form opens on top of everything.
4. The flyout closes.
5. The main form gets the focus after the flyout closes - hiding the non-modal form.

I would like the focus-change to the main form to not occur when the flyout closes.

I have a method that works, but it's a bit laggy because it has to wait for the flyout animation to finish.

Is there a better way? I do not want to make the new window to be modal or AlwaysOnTop.

```
    private void SearchResultClose(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_EvtResultClosed.Set();
    }

    private void SearchResultOpenChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (foSearchResult.IsOpen)
        {
            m_EvtResultClosed.Reset();
        }
    }
```

and

```
<controls:Flyout Position="Top" Header="" x:Name="foSearchResult"
 Height="275" ClosingFinished="SearchResultClose" IsOpenChanged="SearchResultOpenChange">
```

and

```
    private void OpenPersonCard(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selected_person = SearchPersonResultsVM.View.CurrentItem as Editable<Person>;

        if (selected_person != null)
        {
            var card = new PersonFileWindow();
            card.Person = selected_person;
            foSearchResult.IsOpen = false;

            // Wait for it to close, and then show the form.
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    m_EvtResultClosed.WaitOne();
                });
                card.Show();
            }), null);

        }
    }
```

where

```
 private AutoResetEvent m_EvtResultClosed = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the function `IsOpenedChanged` in MahApps' Flyout.cs and we see it calls Focus() on close whether its animated or not. It is also comment :

```
 // focus the Flyout itself to avoid nasty FocusVisual painting (it's visible until the Flyout is closed)
```

But I do not know what it is trying to resolve exactly.

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/1.2.4/MahApps.Metro/Controls/Flyout.cs

The simplest hack is adding Focusable="False" to your flyout as:

```
<controls:Flyout Focusable="False" Position="Top" Header="" x:Name="foSearchResult"Height="275" ClosingFinished="SearchResultClose" IsOpenChanged="SearchResultOpenChange">
```

It works fine here and I can't tell any nasty FocusVisual painting as commented in the source.

Comment: Awesome!  thank you.
I have removed all my ugly semaphoring code as a result.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when opened, the Flyout steals focus for itself, or if `Focusable==false`, for some control within it, even the close button. In any case, focus is not restored to the previous element.

So, just setting `Focusable="False"` probably won't solve the problem.

Instead, Flyout provides the `AllowFocusElement` property to suppress this behavior:

```
<controls:Flyout AllowFocusElement="False" ... >
```